# Modify the \question \part \subparts environment in exam class

Tags: macros, conditionals, exam

I would like to modify the `\question` `\part` and `\subpart` environment to include an extra optional argument.

For example currently exam class has the following `\question[1]` which displays the mark of this question.

I would like to add a new optional argument eg `\question[1][4]` where the 4 will call the command `\fillwithdottedlines{4}`

MWE

```
\documentclass{exam}
\begin{document}
\begin{questions}
    \question[1]
    Question number 1 has 4 lines
    \fillwithdottedlines{2cm}
    % Ideally i would like to write \question[1][2]
    \question
    \begin{parts}
        \part[1]
        This part has 4 lines.
        \fillwithdottedlines{2cm}
        % Ideally i would like to write \part[1][2]
        \part[3]
        This part does not not have lines.
        % Leave as it is.
    \end{parts}
\end{questions}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Not impossible but not easy. Why don't you just define a shorthand? You could write `\newcommand*{\foo}[1][2]{\fillwithdottedlines{#1cm}}` and then use `\foo` or `\foo[4]` if you want more. That's definitely safer than messing the the class' internal macros.

Comment: But I want all the features that come with `\question[1]` for example adding up the total marks, pages numbers etc.